# Multiple attributes with one attribute using js variable

Tags: node.js, pug

Hello I am having problems with Jade and Node.JS

I have the following code in my template:

```
- var css = assets.get('css')
each path in css
  link(rel="stylesheet" href=path)
```

It gives me the following error:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

But If I do the following

```
- var css = assets.get('css')
each path in css
  link(href=path)
```

It seems to work, what am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a comma:

```js
link(rel="stylesheet", href=path)
//           here ---^
```